# Facebook Application Dashboard?

Tags: facebook

Does anyone know the problem with Facebook's Application Dashboard? I have tried for a couple of days to get a app id but every link I use sends me to my FB page- I have typed the URL into the browser and get the same results-- redirected to my page.

Comment: Are you using your account as a Facebook *page* or Facebook *user*